# Issue with deploying Azure project using Powershell 2

Tags: powershell, azure

I used the Azure training kit command

```
New-Deployment 
    -serviceName <YOUR_SERVICE_NAME_LOWER_CASE> 
    -subscriptionId <YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_ID> 
    -certificate (get-item cert:\CurrentUser\MY\<YOUR_CERTIFICATE_THUMBPRINT>) 
    -slot staging 
    –package <PACKAGE_LOCATION> 
    -configuration <CONFIGURATION_LOCATION>  
    -label "v2.0" 
    –storageServiceName <YOUR_STORAGE_SERVICE_NAME_LOWER_CASE>
```

to deploy my Azure app. It was able to upload package to the blob but when Create a new deployment it shows error as:

```
New-Deployment : Cannot access a closed Stream.
At line:1 char:15
+ New-Deployment <<<<  -serviceName mytodo -subscriptionId xxxxxxxxx
8ad-360cdbdc361f -certificate (get-item cert:\CurrentUser\MY\xxxxxxxx
6DD27E3DFF5F7FE24A3FBF) -slot staging -package MyTodo.cspkg -configuration Serv
iceConfiguration.cscfg -label "v1.0" -storageServiceName xxxxx
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-Deployment], ObjectDisposed
   Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Samples.ManagementTools.P
   owerShell.Services.HostedServices.NewDeploymentCommand
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a local proxy (e.g. Fiddler) running? If so, you'll need to disable it.

Also, check the certificate is installed properly and in the right place: follow, to the letter, the instructions here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg271300

in particular noting there are no line breaks or spaces in the path for `(get-Item cert:\CurrentUser\MY\XXXXX)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Base on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg271300, I found I missing create a host service on azure first ha. I thought it will automatically create for me .

Comment: Could you clarify? What was missing?